# How do I calculate averages based upon criteria that exist in other cells

Tags: excel

Perhaps this question is best explained in tables, rather than in words.

I'm trying to turn this table:

```
Site | Year | Value
A    | 1999 | 5
A    | 1999 | 10
A    | 2001 | 12
B    | 1999 | 6
C    | 1996 | 4
C    | 1996 | 10
```

into this table:

```
Site | Year | Value | Year-Average | Site-Average
A    | 1999 | 5     | 7.5          | 9.75
A    | 1999 | 10    | 7.5          | 9.75
A    | 2001 | 12    | 12           | 9.75
B    | 1999 | 6     | 6            | 6
C    | 1996 | 4     | 7            | 8.5
C    | 1996 | 10    | 7            | 8.5
```

If you'll notice, the Year-Average averages duplicate values within *one* year from within *one* site. Then the Site-Average calculates its averages from the Year-Average values.

I can do this manually, but my real data set has many thousands of rows and I am looking for a repeatable procedure to use in the future.

Comment: I posted an idea but deleted it because I can't get the same answers as you show.  Site A has 5+10+12=27, so the average should be 9, no?

Comment: How did you arrive at 8.5 for "C" Shouldn't it be 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for Year-average would be

```
=AVERAGE(IF(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7=B2),$C$2:$C$7,""))
```

And for Site-average

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$D$2:$D$7,""))
```

Enter it as an **array formula** using Ctrl-Shift-Enter into the first cell and copy down the whole column.
If you need to exclude duplicate years when counting the site average, the formula becomes a little longer:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(($A$2:$A$8=A2)*(FREQUENCY(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7=B2),($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7=B2))>0),$D$2:$D$7,""))
```

Note  there's an extra row in the first occurrence of the input range: $A$2:$A$8 rather than $A$2:$A$7.

Comment: I believe you second formula is incorrect. it gives 9 for "A". The correct value is actually 9.75 :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout It's not clear from the question what kind of average OP wants. If you mean to exclude duplicates - I updated the answer with a single formula. And input range doesn't have to be sorted, too ;)

Comment: This looks like the solution I need. And I *do* need to exclude duplicates so your third equation is great!

Answer (score 2):

Use these Array Formulas. You need to press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> after you enter the formulas in the cell

For `Year Average` Put this in Cell D2

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$7=A2)*($B$2:$B$7=B2)*($C$2:$C$7))/COUNT(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,IF($B$2:$B$7=B2,$C$2:$C$7)))
```

I am unsure, how did you arrive at 8.5 for C

**Snapshot**

[image]

**EDIT**

**Here is the way to get Site-Average :)**

To achieve what you want for the Site-Average, we have to use a helper column. See Snapshot

In Cell E2 put this formula

```
=D2
```

In E3 put this formula

```
=IF(OR(A3<>A2,B3<>B2),D3,"")
```

and drag it down.

Now in Cell F2 put this formula

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$7=A2,$E$2:$E$7,""))
```

and press <kbd>CTL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Copy the formula down.

Hide Col E if you need to

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the work you put in. Your equations and panda-34's will likely be just what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the averages by year and site using a pivot table and then use vlookups to append the relevant averages to each row of your initial table.